# How to add line-height based on number of lines of text

Tags: css

Please check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/armikbd/xq6mU/1/).

#### What I want?

1. If there is only one line in `.label`, it will apply `line-height: 30px;` to vertically centering with next input field.
2. If there are multiple lines in `.label`, it will apply `line-height: normal;`

#### Note:

1. I cannot edit HTML
2. Cannot apply javascript or jQuery
3. Cannot use `:first-child`, `:nth-child` pseudo classes, because contents are dynamic.
4. I tried to use `.label{ display: table-cell;}`, but it is not working as `.label` has `float` applied. Again I do not like to use `table-cell`.
5. `.label:first-line` will not work/suitable for this case.
6. `.label:before {
       content: "";
       display: inline-block;
       height: 30px;
       vertical-align: middle;
   }`

   will not work.

#### HTML

```
<form>
    <label>
        <span class="label">Your Name</span>
        <input type="text" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span class="label">Please Give Your Full Name</span>
        <input type="text" />
    </label>
</form>
```

#### CSS

```
form {
    float: left;
    width: 450px;
}
label {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.label {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    line-height: 30px;
}
input {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    padding: 10px;
}
input {
    height: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done in css, aligning everything to top might be your best bet

Comment: have you tried max-height?

Comment: @BrettWeber Where are you referring to use max-height?

Comment: honestly, I am not sure where to apply it now that I am really looking at things. My idea was to allow the height to change as needed for multiple lines, but your requirements make this a tough cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if you remove `float` from the `.label` this should work:

```
label {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.label {
    width: 150px;
    line-height: normal;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xq6mU/3/)

---

*First solution with using margin*

You can try to add `margin-top` to `.label`

```
.label {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
```

I'm not sure that is exactly what you want, you can check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xq6mU/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not think that way. And it works for [this form](http://jsfiddle.net/xq6mU/2/). However, check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/armikbd/xq6mU/1/), where input label goes two lines. In this case top margin will not give desired alignment.

Comment: @Iqbal Ok, I guess I found the root of the evil. Could you check updated answer?